# Кодировка php на сайте

Tags: php, css3, html5, веб-сервер

Есть сайт [ссылка](http://wezom.webazex.com/)
на нем используется следующий код:

```
<span>
&nbsp;<?php 
        ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); 
        setlocale(LC_All, 'ru_RU');
        echo strftime('%A %d %B'); ?>
</span>
```

хэдэр выглядит вот так

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type"
            content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="adaptive.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Alternates" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Курсы PHP</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
</head>
```

Но при этом проблема на сайте имеет место быть. Пробовал ставить 1251 - проблема не решена. Подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: htaccess есть ? если да то внесите в него запись adddefaultcharset utf8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

помог комментарий Максима Ленский

а также нашел еще один вариант ответа:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
```

я раньше писал `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU');`